# Javascript ajax get data undefined from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, google-visualization

I want to build a web page with google charts. I tried to build it with c# as a web form and get data from local database to javascript. But that's not working and i'm having data is undefined in the response of ajax.
This is the code of c#

```
        [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static object[] GetChartData()
    {
        List<GoogleChartData> data = new List<GoogleChartData>();
        //Here MyDatabaseEntities  is our dbContext
        using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            data = dc.GoogleChartDatas.ToList();
        }
        var chartData = new object[data.Count + 1];
        chartData[0] = new object[]{
                "Product Category",
                "Revenue Amount"
            };
        int j = 0;
        foreach (var i in data)
        {
            j++;
            chartData[j] = new object[] { i.Product_Category, i.RevenueAmount };
        }return chartData;
    }
```

and the javascript code is:

```
        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<!-- Javascript Job-->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    var chartData; // globar variable for hold chart data
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

    // Here We will fill chartData

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "GoogleChart.aspx/GetChartData",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                chartData = data.d;
                alert(chartData);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
            }
        }).done(function () {
            // after complete loading data
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            drawChart();
        });
    });


    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
            title: "Company Revenue",
            pointSize: 5
        };

        var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        pieChart.draw(data, options);

    }

</script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
</div>
```

[Database is in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSn6P.png)

PLEASE HELP!! how to get my table data in ajax and put them in chart?

Comment: why `chartData = data.d;` ?

Answer (score 0):

first, recommend **not using** `jsapi` to load the library, according to [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will *only* change the `load` statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

as seen above, the `callback` can be set in the `load` statement

the `callback` will let you know when google charts has loaded, *along with the dom*

thus no need for `setOnLoadCallback` or `$(document).ready`

as for the rest, recommend the following setup...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<!-- Javascript Job-->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    google.charts.load('current', {
      callback: drawChart,
      packages: ['corechart']
    });

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "GoogleChart.aspx/GetChartData",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      }).done(function (data) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data.d);
        var options = {
          title: "Company Revenue",
          pointSize: 5
        };
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        pieChart.draw(data, options);
      }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
      });
    }
</script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
</div>
```

Comment: No, that didn't work with me. I still have no data on the web page

Comment: added to post above

Comment: thanks for adding a picture of the data but i should have been more clear -- it would be helpful to see the contents of `data.d` -- if it is a json object, then using `arrayToDataTable` will not work -- google requires a specific format to create a data table directly from json --> [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) -- using your browser's developer console, please share the result of --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));`