# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string in Google Charts with ASP.NET and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, charts, webforms, google-visualization

I'm trying to display some data in Google Charts but get this error:

> Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string..

This is my first time to use Google Chart in general and I am trying to use with ASP.NET Webforms and SQL Server. I have a WebMethod that returns the data from the database in a format of an array that is bound with Google Chart.

Here's the code of the script:

```
<script>
    var chartData; // globar variable for hold chart data
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

    // Here We will fill chartData

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "../../Pages/Test.aspx/GetSentimentData",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                chartData = data.d;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
            }
        }).done(function () {
            // after complete loading data
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart3);
            drawChart3();
        });
    });


    function drawChart3() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
            title: "Distribution of Sentiment Analysis Results",
            hAxis: { title: 'University'},
            vAxis: { title: 'Number of Tweets' },
            pointSize: 5
        };

        var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        columnChart.draw(data, options);

    }
</script>
```

**So could you please tell me how I can create a Google Column Chart where each item in x-axis will have three series?**

Comment: see last __EDIT__ in answer here --> [Google Bar Chart data preparation — Group by Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40367402/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat, thanks for your help. However, the answer that you referred me to it, has a dummy data not data from database. Actually, I don't know how I can adjust mine based on this reference. So could you please help me based on the code I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once the data table is built,
use a data view to create a new column for each unique sentiment label

then aggregate the data view to remove duplicates and total each column

see following snippet...

```
function drawChart3() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

  // create data view
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  // init column arrays
  var aggColumns = [];
  var viewColumns = [0];

  // build view & agg column for each sentiment label
  data.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (label, index) {
    // add view column
    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === label) {
          return dt.getValue(row, 2);
        }
        return null;
      },
      label: label,
      type: 'number'
    });

    // add agg column
    aggColumns.push({
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      column: index + 1,
      label: label,
      type: 'number'
    });
  });

  // set view columns
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  // agg view by university
  var group = google.visualization.data.group(
    view,
    [0],
    aggColumns
  );

  var options = {
    title: "Distribution of Stanford CoreNLP Sentiment Analysis Results by University",
    hAxis: { title: 'University'},
    vAxis: { title: 'Number of Tweets' },
    pointSize: 5
  };

  var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('stanfrod_sentiment_by_uni_chart_div'));
  columnChart.draw(group, options);  // <-- use agg data table
}
```

---

**note**

recommend **not using** `jsapi` to load the library, according to [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will also change the `load` statement to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

---

**also**

you shouldn't be calling `setOnLoadCallback` more than once

you can depend on google's callback to know when the document is ready

no need for --> `$(document).ready`

once the callback fires, you can draw as many charts as needed

load google, then use ajax to get data, see setup here --> [Javascript ajax get data from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40951082/5090771)

Comment: thanks for your help in this regard. I tried your code snippet and it didn't work. No graph or message is shown and I don't know why.

Comment: Do you think it is because I am still using `jsapi`?

Comment: How do you want to share the sample with you? Do you want me to post the sql script?

Comment: please edit the question with a sample of --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData));` -- and / or update the question with the latest attempt -- did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Finally, I was able to fix it. Thank you so much for your help in this regard.